# Renaming alternate chapter headings

Tags: sectioning

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I've found some similar questions but nothing that exactly addresses my problem.

I'd like to rename *alternate* chapter headings in my book-class LaTeX document. I'm aware of using `\renewcommand` to achieve this for every chapter heading, but can this be modified to only rename alternate chapters?

i.e.

```
for i in [Chapter 1, Chapter 3, Chapter 5, ...]:
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
```

Comment: You could use the `\titleformat` command from the package `titlesec` and use a conditional for odd chapter numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a test to \chaptername itself:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\chaptername{\ifodd\value{chapter}Lecture\else Something else\fi}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A} \chapter{B} \chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

This naturally assume that you are not using the command in some other place where the test it not suited.